# DataGridView overrides my custom row painting

Tags: c#, datagridview, paint

I'm following the example on MSDN for using the RowPrePaint event to custom paint my rows.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint(v=vs.110).aspx

I only want to custom paint some rows, not all. I also have an alternating row style applied.

When I stepped through the debugger I was able to watch the program paint the row according to the example in MSDN (a subtle gradient), but as soon as the RowPrePaint event handler returned the program repainted the row according to its default styles.

How can I keep my custom painting style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs.Handled = true`

```
void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled =true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the answer, but I also had to call `e.PaintCells(e.ClipBounds,DataGridViewPaintParts.All)` before setting `e.Handled = true`, otherwise nothing would be painted.

Comment: @user2320861 - Glad to help. Don't forget to upvote :) Yes you have to call the default painting methods depending on the part which is painted unless you want to override them. But once you are done with the event setting the e.Handled avoids the system from repainting again.