# Scrolling DataGridView botches anything painted by CellPainting and RowPostPaint events

Tags: c#, datagridview, paint

Let me start by saying that I found the following, but none of them had a solution that worked for me.

[Cells gets overlapped and painted when Scroll happens in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35209374/6442320)

[DataGridView overrides my custom row painting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22355180/6442320)

[DataGridView CellPainting Not Fully Working on Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144083/6442320)

---

In both CellPainting and RowPostPaint, I am using `e.Graphics.DrawLine` and when the grid loads everything is drawn as I would expect. I have two problems:

1. When I scroll horizontally, anything that wasn't originally visible on the screen doesn't have my custom painting, and
2. when I scroll back some of the lines that had been painted have shifted to create a line through the middle of a cell, instead of on the border as it was before the scroll.

---

Here are both of my paint events:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    int width = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        width += col.Width;
        if (col.Index % 3 == 0)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, width + 1, e.RowBounds.Top, width + 1, e.RowBounds.Bottom - 1);
    }
}
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    int width = 0;
    if (e.RowIndex == -1)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            width += col.Width;
            if (col.Index % 3 == 0)
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, width + 1, e.CellBounds.Top +1, width + 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 2);
            else
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, width + 1, e.CellBounds.Top +1, width + 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 2);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATED CODE**
I've since combined my paint events into just the `CellPainting` event and made some changes as advised by TaW. Still isn't working but I feel like I'm just missing something small at this point.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex % 3 == 0)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Top + 1, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 2);
        else
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Top + 1, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 2);
    }
    else
        if (e.ColumnIndex % 3 == 0)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Top + 1, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 2);
}
```

Comment: You need to use a relative value for __both__ x __and__ y!! So make that c.CellBounds.Left instead of width.. AlsO: Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: That definitly makes sense! For some reason though, when I make that change nothing gets painted at all. I can see the lines that _should_ be there flicker in/out intermittently though.

Comment: Um sorry , I should have noticed right away: The CellPainting event is called for __each__ Cell, so the loop is wrong!

Comment: Taking out the loop didn't seem to change anything :\ I'm updating the question with my current code since it's changed a bit since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a few steps for proper `CellPainting`:

You need to

- Tell the event that you are **done** with it or else everything is overwritten (1)
- Therfore you also need to make sure that..

  - The **Backgound** (2) and..
  - The **Content** (3) are drawn.

Here is an example:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, 
                                            DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle cr = e.CellBounds;
        e.PaintBackground(cr, true);  //  (2)
        e.PaintContent(cr);           //  (3)

        if (e.ColumnIndex % 2 == 0)
        {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LawnGreen, cr.Right-2, cr.Top + 1, 
                                                    cr.Right-12, cr.Bottom - 2);
        }

        e.Handled = true;  // (1)
    }
```

You can change the order of things, just make sure the background is drawn first!

Note that, contrary to a comment, there is no need to code the `Scroll` event with an `Invalidate`.

Comment: This works for me, but if I try to paint exactly where the cell dividing lines are my lines aren't visible! I can paint anywhere else and it shows up fine. Any idea why? -edit I'm a doofus I was trying to paint outside of the bounds.... Thank you!